# How can I convert my text file to a CSV?

Tags: excel, perl, csv

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
a1: sample1
b1: sample2
c1: sample3
d1: sample4
    sample5
    sample0 

a1: sample_1
b1: sample_2
c1: sample_3
d1: sample_4
    sample_5

a1: sample_11
b1: sample_22
c1: sample_33
d1: sample_44
```

I need to convert it to a CSV that I can access in Excel. The final output should look like this:

```
a1, b1, c1, d1
sample1,sample2,sample3,"sample4 sample5"
sample_1,sample_2,sample_3,"sample_4 sample_5"
sample_11,sample_22,sample_33,"sample_44 sample_55"
```

sample 4 and sample5 and sample0, they all belong to d1, ie. in one row.
So, basically d1 will be one cell and it would have three values like:

a1          b1      c1         d1     row0

sample1  sample2 sample3  sample4     row1
                          sample5     row1
                          sample0     row1

sample_1 sample_2 sample_3 sample_4   row2 
                           sample_5   row2

d1 is one cell with 2 values now.

I am able to parse the text file and get the values as need.
Not able to get the column d1 to be in the way required.
How can I do this?

Need a Perl script to do this?
Any suggestions?

```
open(file, "f1.txt");
open(csv, ">+f2.csv");
 while($line =<file>)
   chmop;
   if($line =~/a1)
   {
   @arr1 = split(/:/,$line)
   print csv "@arr1[1],";
   }

   if($line =~/b2)
   {
   @arr2 = split(/:/,$line)
   print csv "@arr2[1],";
   }

close(file);
close(csv);
```

This is the code I have until now.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show us what your did so far and add more details to your question!

Comment: To be in CSV format, you don't need spaces between `a1,`, `b1,`, `c1,`, and `d1`. Nor do you need quotes around fields containing spaces.

Comment: Editing "need a Perl script" into your question adds nothing (it was already tagged [tag:perl] to begin with). Uli Köhler is asking what specific issue you're having with the Perl code you wrote. You did write *something*, didn't you?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the content of the file in a scaler like this:

```
my $input = "a1: sample1
b1: sample2
c1: sample3
d1: sample4, sample5

a1: sample_1
b1: sample_2
c1: sample_3
d1: sample_4, sample_5

a1: sample_11
b1: sample_22
c1: sample_33
d1: sample_44, sample_55";
```

Then you can use some regex(**when the input is similar to your description in question**):

```
## considering the four lines each time and no empty line as well
$input =~ s/([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)/"$1","$2","$3","$4"/msg;

## removing a1: things
$input =~ s/[a-z]\d+:\s*//ig;

## removing comma around texts amid of "    ,   "
$input =~ s/(?<!"),(?!")//ig;

## finally output!
print '"a1","b1","c1","d1"'. "\n$input";
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

local ( $/, $" ) = ( '', ',' );
print "a1,b1,c1,d1\n";

while (<>) {
    my @fields = map { /:\s+(.+)/; $1 } split /\n/;
    print qq/@fields[ 0 .. 2 ],"$fields[3]"\n/;
}
```

Command-line usage: `perl script.pl inFile > outFile`

Output on your dataset:

```
a1,b1,c1,d1
sample1,sample2,sample3,"sample4, sample5"
sample_1,sample_2,sample_3,"sample_4, sample_5"
sample_11,sample_22,sample_33,"sample_44, sample_55"
```

The script sets `$/ = ''` for paragraph mode, to read your file a chunk at a time.  It `split`s the chunks on newlines, then captures the wanted field info using a regex.  Double quotes are placed around the last field, and the array slice is interpolated, which prints `,` between the fields due to the earlier `$" = ','`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how this should be:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

open(my $TXT, "<", 'inabcd.txt') or die "Cound not open";
open(my $CSV, ">", "outabcd.csv");

my $rowcount = 0;
my %h  = ();

while(my $line = <$TXT>) {
    if($line =~ /^$/) {
        next;
    }
    chomp($line);
   my ($key, @data) = split(':',$line);

   if (exists $h{$key}) {
        $rowcount = $h{$key}->{'rowcount'};
        $rowcount++;
        }

   $h{$key}->{$rowcount} = \@data;
   $h{$key}->{'rowcount'} = $rowcount;
}
my @header = ();
foreach my $el (keys %h) {
    if($el ne 'rowcount') {
        push(@header, $el);
    }
}

my $header = join(',', @header);

print $CSV "$header". "\n";

my $r = 0;
while($r <= $rowcount) {
    foreach my $e (@header) {
            print("@{$h{$e}->{$r}}" . ",");
            print $CSV "@{$h{$e}->{$r}}" . ",";
    }
    print $CSV "\n";
    $r++;
}

close($TXT);
close($CSV);
```